# Geometric intuition for algebraic geometry and commutative algebra

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

There is a nice quote which I forget the author and precise phrasing but says something to the effect of:

> Geometry is the study using intuitive pictures in low dimensions to argue more generally but while being careful to not use any of the specifics of the low dimension picture.

Intuition is best built by working with lots of examples. In differential geometry, we can get quite a mental picture of manifolds in low dimensions. This helps to build a good intuition for abstract properties of manifolds and how they work generally.
I struggle to do this with algebraic geometry. A simple example of a variety might be the $V(x^2+y^2)$ with $x^2+y^2\in k[x,y]$. But since we work of algebraically closed fields, already if we take $k=\mathbb C$ we are working with four real dimensions.

Asking for geometric intuition on a subject is a rather broad question. I think I should give some specific questions to help guide the kind of answers I am looking for. If you would like to ignore these and answer more generally about geometric intuition you have please feel free to do so.

- How do you deal with the disconnect of thinking of pictures over $\mathbb R$ with working with objects over $k$?
- We can draw the spectrum of a ring, is this the only way to think about rings geometrically or do you have a good mental picture of a ring by itself?
- In differential geometry, when someone says manifold I'll immediately picture a potatoe shaped blobule with possibly a hole, what pictures or key examples do you got to in algebraic geometry?

At the moment, a variety, its coordinate ring, and sheaf of regular functions just feel like abstract objects that I formally push around using definitions and theorems. Any illumination on this subject would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Eisenbud--Harris, Chapter II, has many examples of schemes along with pictures. There's a section on schemes over non-algebraically closed fields which might help with the first point. Regarding the second point, I know of no better visualisation of a ring than through its spectrum.

Comment: As for the third point: honestly there are so many examples (again Chapter II has a bunch) but I always emphasise that the 'canonical' example should be plain ol' affine or projective varieties over a field. These aren't representative of all schemes, but at its core algebraic geometry is still about solving polynomials, and it's easy to forget that when delving deeply into exotic examples and counterexamples.

Comment: Mumford has a famous picture of the spectrum of $\mathbf{Z}[x]$, you can see if that is what you are looking for. For your first point, I think that the answer is "you don't": pictures over $\mathbf{R}$ can be helpful to build intuition, but are rarely useful in proving anything, especially when the field has positive characteristic or some other property (it's hard to plot anything over $\mathbf{F}_p(t)$ for example).

Comment: To build on Jeroen van der Meer's second comment, you should think of any shape given by polynomial equations, such as elliptic curves (or any curve), the twisted cubic, surfaces, or other stuff in low dimension.

Comment: I think the quote to which you're referring is due to Poincaré: "La géométrie est l'art de bien raisonner sur des figures mal faites", i.e., "Geometry is the art of reasoning well about poorly made figures". Also, I have to add..."potatoe"? Dan Quayle, is that you?

Comment: There are certainly other ways of visualizing rings, but the way to visualize them often depends on what sort of ring it is. For instance, rings of integers and their ideals can be viewed as lattices using Minkowski's [geometry of numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometry_of_numbers). The simplest example of this is viewing the Gaussian integers $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ as the square lattice in the complex plane.

Comment: I would consider looking at Reid’s book on undergraduate commutative algebra, and then his book on undergraduate algebraic geometry.

Comment: The books mentioned so far by Eisenbud/Harris, and by Reid, are greats books, but I would suggest looking at chapter 3 of Vakil's notes on algebraic geometry for a more modernly written take.